# winforms - point form to clone

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

My program class has:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

in form1 class I have:

```
model = new Model(this);

    private void userEnteredText()
 {
       Model clonedModel = (Model)model.Clone();
       this.myButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10,5);
       MessageBox.Show("buttons made small");
       this = clonedModel;
      MessageBox.Show("clone complete and buttons restored to orig size");
}
```

in model class I have:

```
    public Model(Form1 form1)
    {
        myform = form1;
    }

public object Clone()
{
   return new Model(myform);
}
```

My initial form1 object has the size of buttons really large. After the user enters a value in a textbox: I clone the model object and call a method that makes the buttons really small. How can I then set the model object to point back to the original model object with large buttons?

I'm getting this error:
"Cannot assign to this because it is read-only"

I know I can just change the button size but I need to clone the entire object because there are other original variables that I want reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question - is it expected behaviour that whilst clone both models references the same `Form`? `Clone()` method just creates a new instance of Model but it still reference the same `Form` object,

You can persist state of the initial model in an other private field like

```
private Model backupModel;
```

and before applying a user-defined values just backup and later restore current model like:

```
 private void userEnteredText()
 {
       this.backupModel = model;     
       Model clonedModel = (Model)model.Clone();
       this.myButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10,5);
       MessageBox.Show("buttons made small");
       model = this.backupModel;     
       MessageBox.Show("clone complete and buttons restored to orig size");
 }
```

Comment: after you assign clonedModel it is not used, is that a typo?

Comment: I want to be able to clone the model and form so that when I restore it will show the original form button's size (ie before the user action).

Comment: @toop : so the problem is in clone method which is not does clone of Form. SO you clone Model but form still the same. I would suggest use Deep Copy for this purposes using binary serialization